how to use inquirer with NodeNext?
import inquirer from "inquirer";

const answers : {
    Sentance:string;
}= await inquirer.prompt(
    {
        name:"Sentance",
        type:"input",
        message:"Enter sentance to count"
    }
)

const words = answers.Sentance.trim().split(" ")

I get this error:

No overload matches this call.The last overload gave the following error.Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Pick<NumberConfig | InputConfig | { message: string; choices: readonly (Separator | Choice<unknown>)[]; pageSize?: number | undefined; loop?: boolean | undefined; default?: unknown; theme?: { ...; } | undefined; } | ... 5 more ... | EditorConfig, "message"> | AsyncGetterFunction<...>'.ts(2769)types.d.mts(30, 9): The expected type comes from property 'message' which is declared here on type 'Readonly<DistributiveMerge<NumberConfig | InputConfig | { message: string; choices: readonly (Separator | Choice<unknown>)[]; pageSize?: number | undefined; loop?: boolean | undefined; default?: unknown; theme?: { ...; } | undefined; } | ... 5 more ... | EditorConfig, { ...; }>>'how to solve this error using typescript .

I tried
npm i --save-dev @types/inquirer 

and
npm install typescript@latest 

but error is not solved

promot expect an array wrap  your answer with [] : await inquirer.prompt([])
